# How to insert a record with only default values?

Tags: sql-server

If I have an SQL table with all default columns (e.g. identity column + any number of columns all with default values), what is the SQL statement to insert a row with no explicit values given?

```
insert MyTable /* ( doh, no fields! ) */ 
-- values( doh, no values! )
```

What's the trick?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is a part of the `INSERT` syntax

```
INSERT INTO TableName DEFAULT VALUES
```

Read more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

Comment: +1! This is the correct answer! One small note: for SQLite databases, `INTO` is [mandatory](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). So the syntax becomes: `INSERT INTO TableName DEFALUT VALUES`

Comment: If using an `OUTPUT` clause, make sure to put it before the `DEFAULT VALUES` 
`INSERT INTO TableName OUTPUT DEFAULT VALUES`

Comment: Is it possible to insert multiple rows of default values with a single `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @Pang Solution for multiple rows below

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `DEFAULT` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**The accepted answer only works for one row, not for multiple rows.**

Let us assume you know how many rows to insert, but you want all default values. You cannot do the following, for instance

```sql
INSERT MyTable
SELECT DEFAULT VALUES  -- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'.
FROM SomeQueryOrView;
-- or
INSERT MyTable
DEFAULT VALUES  -- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
FROM SomeQueryOrView;
```

**Instead we can hack `MERGE` to do this**

```sql
MERGE INTO myTable
USING (SELECT SomeValue FROM SomeQueryOrView) s
ON 1 = 0  -- never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT DEFAULT VALUES;
```

A bonus benefit is that we can `OUTPUT` data from columns which are not being inserted:

```sql
MERGE INTO myTable
USING (SELECT SomeValue FROM SomeQueryOrView) s
ON 1 = 0  -- never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT DEFAULT VALUES
OUTPUT inserted.Id, s.SomeValue;
```