# MySQL insert row with only default values

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to insert a row with only the default values (which I will then update later since I need the ID autoincremented field)

This works in SQL Server ([How to insert a record with only default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764312/how-to-insert-a-record-with-only-default-values))

```
insert into myTable DEFAULT  VALUES;
```

But how can I accomplish this in MySQL:

I also tried:

```
insert into myTable;
```

which fails. I know I can work around with the standard insert syntax, but there are a lot of columns in my table so a simple syntax if it exists would be helpful.

Comment: I update my post, you can even use `INSERT INTO myTable () VALUES();`  look https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html for more info ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will do it :

```
INSERT INTO `myTable` (`id`)
VALUES 
    (null),
    (null);
-- or 
INSERT INTO `myTable` () 
VALUES();
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04296/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `title` varchar(5) DEFAULT '***')
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1, 'hi'),
    (2, 'hello')
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`)
VALUES
    (null),
    (null)
;
INSERT INTO Table1 () VALUES();
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * from Table1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04296/1/0)**:

```
| id | title |
|----|-------|
|  1 |    hi |
|  2 | hello |
|  3 |   *** |
|  4 |   *** |
|  5 |   *** |
```