# Insert into sqlite with default value

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm working on a android program with SQLite. I'm trying to create a datebase with two tables related by a foreign key, and I want to automaticaly populate one entry of the mother table using the insert funcion. But this generate an SQLite error.

Here is the funcion to insert an entry into the mother class

```
private long new_event(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    long id = db.insert("EVENT",null,values);
    return id;
}
```

Here is the function to insert an entry into the child class

```
public long new_specific_event(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    long id_event = new_event(db);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id_event", id_event);
    values.put("whatsoever", "whatsoever");
    long id = db.insert("SPECIFIC_EVENT",null,values);
    return id;
}
```

Here is the mother table

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, created_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

and here is the child table

```
CREATE TABLE SPECIFIC_EVENT (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_event NUMBER,whatsoever TEXT,FOREIGN KEY(id_event) REFERENCES EVENT(id));
```

This result into the following error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "null": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO EVENT(null) VALUES (NULL)
```

I could do it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764312/how-to-insert-a-record-with-only-default-values) and the db.execSQL() funcion, but then I have no access to the id of the entry I just create. 
So, how can I use the insert funcion to insert an entry with just default value?

Comment: Why would you want to insert something and not have it assigned a value?

Comment: The current time is inserted by default so that I'm actually assigning a value:

Comment: No, but why would you not want that to have a unique ID?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You mean merge EVENT and SPECIFIC_EVENT? Because I want to create SPECIFIC_EVENT1 and SPECIFIC_EVENT2 and maybe more with different caracteristics. But it might be that this is not a smart way.

Answer (score 0):

With `ContentValues` you need to put at least one value. To get a default value, put a null for a value for a column:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.putNull("_id");
long id = db.insert("EVENT",null,values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a completely empty row is not possible, so the [insert() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) has the parameter `nullColumnHack` to allow you to specify a column that gets a NULL value in this case:

```java
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
long id = db.insert("EVENT", "_id", values);
```