# How do I insert a new record to a table containing just an IDENTITY column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a single-column table where the column is a primary key and clustered index. It is used on other tables to relate records together.   It doesn't seem an `Insert` statement is the way to go, there's no other columns to populate. It's a bit cumbersome to `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` off and on, etc.

I just need to "increment" the primary key of the table to the next integer value.

I believe it's an easy problem to solve, but I'm at that stage of mental exhaustion where the wheel is still spinning but the hamster is dead.

Here is a script to recreate the table I'm working with.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PKOnly]
(
    [Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PKOnly] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: For formatting just highlight the code block and hit the `{}` button on top of the editor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a record with only default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764312/how-to-insert-a-record-with-only-default-values)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `DEFAULT VALUES`:

```
INSERT dbo.PKOnly DEFAULT VALUES;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64b86845a6ed098f6d20ccd36fe348f3)

Note this will also work if you have other columns with defaults.